# Can not change sash title in AppleWatch notification

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I am currently programming an application for AppleWatch which display notifications. 
However, the name of the app is too long to appear correctly in sash title. 
I want to rename it.

In some post, i saw that we must change the "bundle display name" of the watch app info.plist. 
But it does not work. How can i make this change ?

Answer (score 1):

In your project there is the App folder and the Watchkit Extension folder, each of which contains an Info.plist file. Change the Bundle Display Name in "App" folder.

I'm referencing Xcode 7 Beta 6(7A192o).

Comment: I use XCode 6.4 and if I want to test on XCode 7, I must upgrade my project in Swift 2.0 and I do not want to do this for now.

Comment: But if i change the Bundle Display Name in my "App" folder, it will change the name of my iPhone application. I do not want this. I want that sash notification display the Bundle Display Name that i set for the AppleWatch application.

Comment: Natasha the Robot has a nice tutorial on this here http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-actionable-notifications/  and you can download the app from GitHub here: https://github.com/NatashaTheRobot/WatchKitNotificationDemo. In Xcode 6.4 it looks like the .plist file you want to edit is under the Watch App/Supporting Files. I hope this helps.